# Change project deployment name

Tags: oracle, jdeveloper, bpel

I have a bpel project in jdev, the name is: Project2. By default the deployment name is the same with project name. 
How to change the deployment name in EM into something else? ex: BalanceTransaction

Answer (score 0):

Which Jdev version do you use?
The name you are talking about ifs the context root, I guess. This can be altered in the view controller project settings under j2ee node. Or you change it right while you deploy the application

Comment: Thx for the reply...i'm using 11.1.1.5.0

Comment: I couldn't change it at deployment because it's greyed out. i've changed the project properties on JEE node, still the same project name appear in EM

Answer (score 0):

u can change the name in bpel.xml and then if you deploy using ant script it will get deployed with the name u gave in bpel.xml but ur local project name will be the old one itself.